# Firebase Analytics missing event data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am logging several **predefined** events. Some of them are as follows:

- `kFIREventSelectContent` (select_content) has 2 parameters:

  - `kFIRParameterContentType`
  - `kFIRParameterItemID`
- `kFIREventShare` (share) has 2 parameters:

  - `kFIRParameterContentType`
  - `kFIRParameterItemID`
- `kFIREventJoinGroup` (group_id) has 1 parameter:

  - `kFIRParameterGroupID`
- `kFIREventUnlockAchievement` (achievement_id) has 1 parameter:

  - `kFIRParameterAchievementID`

However, when I want to see details of the logged events, it only shows them for `kFIREventSelectContent` (select_content) and not others. To be more specific, I can't see "Content", "GroupID" and "AchievementID" sections in "share", "group_id" and "achievement_id" respectively.

These are the line of codes that I used for each event type:

```
FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName(kFIREventSelectContent, parameters: [kFIRParameterContentType:"fg_filter", kFIRParameterItemID:fgName])
FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName(kFIREventShare, parameters: [kFIRParameterContentType:"fg_filter", kFIRParameterItemID:fgName])
FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName(kFIREventJoinGroup, parameters: [kFIRParameterGroupID : "\(index)"])
FIRAnalytics.logEventWithName(kFIREventUnlockAchievement, parameters: [ kFIRParameterAchievementID : "\(index)"])
```

**Event Data**

`kFIREventSelectContent` - This has all the data

[image]

`kFIREventShare` - "Content" section is missing

[image]

`kFIREventJoinGroup` - "GroupID" section is missing

[image]

`kFIREventUnlockAchievement` - "AchievementID" section is missing

[image]

What would be the reason for this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I understood from their videos, you need more data to be collected in order to be aggregated and shown in the console as full info. In this video they said about this, but regarding to User Properties
https://youtu.be/V9VwqFqIu_k?t=5m18s